# Sparsely checking out subtrees into a different directory

Tags: git

I would like to get a copy of subtrees `src0` `src1` as they were at commit `v1.0.0` into a directory named out/, without checking out out any other files.

I've tried:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
printf '%s\n' src{0,1}  >> .git/info/sparse-checkout 
GIT_WORK_TREE=out git read-tree -mu v1.0.0
```

But this gives me:

```
error: Entry 'src0/a' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

The above was a simplified attempt, actually. To be more precise, my repo has

```
/src0
/src1
```

and I would like to check out each of these separately 
into

```
out/src_zero
out/src_one
```

where `out/` is a directory that doesn't belong to the repo.
Is what I'm trying to do possible? How can I achieve it?